# Onreceiver in broadcast not working in while receive the sms

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

After incoming message in mobile number **onReceive()** not working.Please help me for finding solution to this problem.
    This is my code please check it and correct me if I am wrong.

```
    public class IncomingSms extends BroadcastReceiver {
        Context con;
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            this.con = context;
            if(intent.getAction().equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"))
            {
                Log.e("IncomingSms", "onReceive..");
                final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
                try {
                    if (bundle != null) {
                        for (String key : bundle.keySet())
                            Log.e("okkk", key + "//   " + bundle.getString(key));

                        final Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                        for (int i = 0; i < pdusObj.length; i++) {
                            SmsMessage currentMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdusObj[i]);
                            String phoneNumber = currentMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
                            String senderNum = phoneNumber;
                            String message = currentMessage.getDisplayMessageBody();

                            try {
                                if (senderNum.equals("TA-DOCOMO")) {
                                    CodeVerificationActivity Sms = new CodeVerificationActivity();
                                    Sms.recivedSms(message);
                                }
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                            }

                        }
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }

    }
```

This my manifest file code that used.please tell me the right way if i missed something  in code then correct me.Actually i was doing reading incoming message automatically in android to verify OTP. This is very important for me.  thanks in advance

```
   <receiver android:name=".Util.IncomingSms"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter android:priority="999">
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />

            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Comment: where is your activity class where you are calling this

Comment: @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        try {
            registerReceiver(new IncomingSms(), new IntentFilter("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

Answer (score 1):

Are you checking on Marshmallow. Then allow the Permission for the App from setting.

Or Try this.

```
public class SMSBroadcast extends BroadcastReceiver {

final SmsManager manager = SmsManager.getDefault();

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

    try {
        if (bundle != null) {
            final Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");

            for (int i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++) {
                SmsMessage currentmessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
                String phoneNumber = currentmessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();

                String message = currentmessage.getDisplayMessageBody();

                Toast.makeText(context, "number " + phoneNumber + " message :" + message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            }


        }


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

}
}
```

Manifest.xml

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <receiver android:name="com.inficare.avinashverma.googlecloudmessagingdemo.broadcast.SMSBroadcast">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"></action>
        </intent-filter>

    </receiver>

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 1):

okay first change your code like this

```
public class IncomingSms extends BroadcastReceiver {
public static final String SMS_BUNDLE = "pdus";
 String address;
 SmsMessage smsMessage;
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Bundle intentExtras = intent.getExtras();
    if (intentExtras != null) {
        Object[] sms = (Object[]) intentExtras.get(SMS_BUNDLE);
        for (int i = 0; i < sms.length; ++i) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                String format = intentExtras.getString("format");
                 smsMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) sms[i], format);
            }
            else {
                smsMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) sms[i]);
            }
           // SmsMessage smsMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) sms[i]);

             address = smsMessage.getOriginatingAddress();



        }
       // Toast.makeText(context, smsMessageStr, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        //this will update the UI with message
        YourActivity inst = Youractivity.instance();//write your activity 
        // where you are checking for message.
        inst.updateList(address);
    }
}
 }
```

Then inside your activity class

```
public static YourActivity instance() {
    return inst;
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    inst = this;
}

 public void updateList(final String smsMessage) {



        if (smsMessage.equalsIgnoreCase("IM-DOCOMO")) {

    Toast.makeText(VerifyNumber.this, "Successfully verified",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }

Then in onresume and onpause register your receiver so that you need to add 
 your receiver in manifest
public void onResume(){
     super.onResume();
     IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
        try{
        registerReceiver(broadCastReceiver, filter);  
        }catch(IllegalArgumentException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
 }

 public void onPause()
  {
     super.onPause();
      try  {
            unregisterReceiver(broadCastReceiver);

              } catch(IllegalArgumentException e){
                  e.printStackTrace();
              }
  }
```